# How Can I display my Current value into Bold in lightning-datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, account, lightning-datatable, hierarchy

I am trying to create a Custom Account Hierarchy

[image: Standard Account Hierarchy]

Therefore I need to indicate my Current record in LWC. I am trying to make the 'Current' word Bold only but it is not working. Please advise any suggestions.

[image]

Below is my Code:

.Js file:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccountHierarchy from '@salesforce/apex/AccountHierarchyController.getAccountHierarchy';

export default class AccountHierarchyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track childAccounts = [];
    @track showHierarchy = false;
    @track currentValue = 'Current';
    @api recordId = null; // Assuming recordId is defined elsewhere in your component
    @track childAccountId;
    columns = [
                { label: 'Diary', type: 'button-icon', initialWidth: 50, typeAttributes: { iconName: 'utility:note', name: 'viewDetails', title: 'View Diary' } },
                { label: 'Hierarchy', fieldName: 'hierarchy', type: 'html', initialWidth: 100, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left', type: 'html' }, wrapText: true },
                { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', type: 'text', initialWidth: 100, wrapText: true },
                { label: 'Primary Contact', fieldName: 'contactName', type: 'text', initialWidth: 150},
                { label: 'BLC User Link', fieldName: 'bLCUserLink', type: 'url', initialWidth: 140, },
                { label: 'BLC User Status', fieldName: 'bLCUserStatus', type: 'text', initialWidth: 150 },
                { label: 'BLC Seller Segment', fieldName: 'blcSellerSegment', type: 'text', initialWidth: 170 },
                { label: 'BLC Buyer Segment', fieldName: 'blcBuyerSegment', type: 'text', initialWidth: 170 },
                { label: 'Created Date', fieldName: 'createdDate', type: 'date', initialWidth: 140, },
            // Add other columns as needed
            ];
    connectedCallback() {
        this.fetchAccountHierarchy();
    }

    fetchAccountHierarchy() {
        getAccountHierarchy({ accountId: this.recordId })
            .then(result => {
                this.showHierarchy = true;
                this.childAccounts = result.map(record => ({
                    ...record,
                    hierarchy: this.buildHierarchy(record),
                    name: record.name,
                    contactName: record.contactName,
                    bLCUserLink: record.bLCUserLink,
                    bLCUserStatus: record.bLCUserStatus,
                    blcSellerSegment: record.blcSellerSegment,
                    blcBuyerSegment: record.blcBuyerSegment,
                    createdDate: record.createdDate,
                }));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.showHierarchy = false;
                console.error('Error fetching child records', error);
            });
        }
    
    buildHierarchy(account) {
        let hierarchy = account.parentName ? account.parentName + ' : ' : '';
        hierarchy += account.name;

        if (account.Id === this.recordId) { 
            hierarchy += '<b>' + this.currentValue + '</b>'; //'<b>: Current</b>'; //' ' + this.currentValue; // '\'<b>\'' + this.currentValue + '\'</b>\'';
        }
        return hierarchy;
    }

    handleRowAction(event) {        
        if (event.detail.action.name === 'viewDetails') {
            this.showHierarchy = false;
            let dataRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));
            this.childAccountId = dataRow['Id'];

            const row = event.detail.row;
            console.log('View Details clicked for:', row);
            console.log('View Details clicked Account:', this.childAccountId);
            this.isNotesAvailable = true;
        }
    }

    handleCancel(event) {
        //this.isModalOpen = false;
        this.isNotesAvailable = false;
    }
    handleClose(event){
        const response = event.detail;
        this.isNotesAvailable = !(response.closeWindlow);
        this.showHierarchy = true;
    }
}
```

.Html file:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Hierarchy 4" icon-name="standard:account">
        <template if:true={showHierarchy}>
            <lightning-datatable 
                key-field="Id" data={childAccounts} 
                columns={columns} 
                hide-checkbox-column="true"
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
        <template if:false={showHierarchy}>
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <p>No data available</p>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={isNotesAvailable}>
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large"
                aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true">
        
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <div class="slds-modal__content">
                        <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_medium">
                            <c-diary record-id={childAccountId} onclosewindowevent={handleClose}
                                onupdatediaryicon={handleDiaryIcon} onpinnedentryevent={handlePinnedEntry}></c-diary>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
            <!-- <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>-->
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Right now it is showing Like This:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider a custom column type, as discussed in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-table-custom-types.html).